# Linking against a library which links other libraries

Tags: c++, dll, sfml, dynamic-linking

This question is in the context of dynamic-link-libraries using g++ under Windows.

Please help me understand something.
I have a library, SoundManager, which I compile like this:

```
$(COMPILER) -o ./bin/SoundManager.dll ./src/SoundManager.cpp -shared -Wl,--out-implib,./lib/libSoundManager.a -shared -DSM_BUILD_DLL $(INCLUDE_PATHS) $(STANDARD) $(OPTIONS) $(LIB_PATHS) -lsfml-system -lsfml-audio
```

That is, it's a library containing a class which handles sound playing, linking against SFML sound libraries.

Now, I have another library, MyLibrary, in which I want to use the SoundManager class which was compiled into SoundManager.dll. I tried this:

```
$(COMPILER) -o ./bin/MyLibrary.dll ./src/MyLibrary.cpp -shared -Wl,--out-implib,./lib/libMyLibrary.a -shared -DSW_BUILD_DLL $(INCLUDE_PATHS) $(STANDARD) $(OPTIONS) $(LIB_PATHS) -lSoundManager
```

At the end there I link against libSoundManager.a. (LIB_PATHS contains the path to where the libSoundManager.a is located.)

However, this doesn't work. I get the following error messages:

```
undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf5SoundD1Ev'
undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf11SoundBufferD1Ev'
```

This tells me that I need to link against some import libraries which are missing. If I add

```
-lsfml-system -lsfml-audio
```

so I compile MyLibrary as this:

```
$(COMPILER) -o ./bin/MyLibrary.dll ./src/MyLibrary.cpp -shared -Wl,--out-implib,./lib/libMyLibrary.a -shared -DSW_BUILD_DLL $(INCLUDE_PATHS) $(STANDARD) $(OPTIONS) $(LIB_PATHS) -lSoundManager -lsfml-system -lsfml-audio
```

then it compiles!

**Question:** Why do I need to link against

```
-lsfml-system -lsfml-audio
```

when compiling MyLibrary? I have already linked against them when compiling SoundManager, and I link against libSoundManager.a when I compile MyLibrary. Shouldn't the DLL lookup table already be taken care of in libSoundManager.a?

Thanks.

Comment: A Windows DLL is more like an executable than like a static library. It has to contain (or dynamically link in) all that it needs. It gets nothing from the context it's used in.

Comment: But SoundManager already links to sfml-system and sfml-audio. When I compile MyLibrary I link against SoundManager. Half the point of creating a SoundManager library in the first place is so that I don't have to "care" about the underlying SFML objects, they are wrapped in my SoundManager class (inside the SoundManager library). Having to link against smfl-system and sfml-audio against defeats that purpose.

Comment: Well, you'll need to find out why MyLibrary is calling these functions, even though SoundManager is supposed to take care of all sound.   Such a dependency leaks pretty easily into a library, these are destructors that are often declare inline in a .h file.  Biggest problem is that this is not your code, all you can do is avoid #including that .h file.  Or to put it another way, your SoundManager.h file must not use the Sound and SoundBuffer classes.  Probably not easy.

Comment: @HansPassant I see, MyLibrary creates an instance of SoundManager, SoundManager indeed used Sound and SoundBuffer classes. So basically, including my SoundManager.h file in MyLibrary causes some functions in the SFML-libraries to be called and therefore these function calls are made from MyLibrary, so it would need to link against the sfml import libraries. In this particular case I guess I don't have much of a choice, since it's not my code. Also, I guess it wouldn't help matters to put pointers to Sound and Soundbuffer in SoundManager, if the function calls are made inline in SFML/Audio.hpp.